# Green kernel for Dirichlet problem of Stokes flow PDE's $\nabla p = \Delta\vec{v}, \nabla\cdot\vec{v}=0$ on a sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

It is well known that except Poisson problem also the Dirichlet problem

$$\Delta u = 0, \qquad u = u_0 \; \text{at}\; \partial B_1(0)$$

possesses in 3D (actually in any dimension) an exact (in a sense of one integral) solution

$$u(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \oint_{B_R(0)} u_0(\vec{x}') \frac{R^2-|\vec{x}|^2}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|^2}dS'$$

Similarly, decomposition into components yields a formula for the vector Dirichlet problem

$$\Delta \vec{A} = 0, \qquad \vec{A} = \vec{A}_0 \; \text{at}\; \partial B_R(0)$$

has a solution

$$\vec{A}(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \oint_{B_R(0)} \vec{A}_0(\vec{x}') \frac{R^2-|\vec{x}|^2}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|^3}dS'$$

My question is, I am solving a different problem (hydrodynamics) namely a system of the Stokes flow equations :

$$\nabla p = \Delta\vec{v},\qquad \nabla\cdot\vec{v}=0$$

After taking a curl clearly $\Delta p=0$. Let us suppose $p$ vanishes at infinity. Given a boundary condition

$$\vec{v} = \vec{v}_0 \; \text{at}\; \partial B_R(0)$$

is there a similar general solution for $\vec{v}$ (and $p$) using nothing more than an appropriate Green function?

Comment: The curl of the gradient is zero. You should obtain the biharmonic equation $\Delta^2\phi = 0$, where $\phi$ is the stream function.

Comment: @Chee Han First you have to show that a restriction for stream function defined $\vec{v}=\nabla \times \vec{\phi}$ namely $\nabla\cdot\vec{\phi}$ will not cut the solution. Then please tell me how to proceed further since the boundary is no longer Dirichlet, but Neumann type namely $\nabla\times\vec{\phi} = \vec{v}_0$ ať $B_R(0)$, what to do? Since the vector field $\vec{v}_0$ Is generally $\varphi,\theta$ dependent, I doubt you can write the stream function as a scalar function only...

Comment: I didn't notice that you want to solve over a sphere, my apologies. I merely want to point out that $\nabla\times\nabla p = 0$ (in Cartesian coordinates), but I don't know now if that continues to hold in spherical coordinates. True, but it turns out that you could [(See here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_stream_function#Spherical_coordinates). I am not claiming that I know how to solve it even then, but given that Stokes flow past a sphere is well-studied, I would assume that Stokes flow inside a sphere has been studied too (I infer this from you quoting Dirichlet problem).

Comment: @Chee Han That is indeed true, there exists a solution for which $\vec{v}=0$ ať $B_R(0)$ namely $$\vec{v}=\nabla\times\left[\frac{\rho v_\infty}{2}\left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{R}{2r}\right)\hat{\varphi}\right]$$. My problem is searching for a solution where you allow the fluid to flow inside a sphere and this influx is given by $\vec{v}_0$ some known function. The question is how does the velocity field looks like in are outside (or even inside) that region.